# Using fa.plot: how to label datapoints with variable names?

Tags: r, psych, factor-analysis

I've been consulting this site for a while but only now signed up. I have a very basic question about plotting factor analysis results using the fa.plot function, and I'm sure the answer is embarrassingly simple but I can't figure it out.

Using the fa.plot function with no specifications, I get a graph where my items are labeled with row *numbers*, but I want it to be row *names*. I tried all sorts of things with the argument labels= but that didn't help. Using fa.diagram, my items are labeled by their names, as I want it to be.

Perhaps as a secondary question, are there other popular ways to display factor analysis findings?

Thank you!

[The graph I want to improve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izVFO.jpg)

**Edit:** Upon request, here is some code.

```
evs <- read.dta("ZA3780_v3-0-1.dta")
evs <- subset(evs, select=c(v225:o38))
evs <- na.omit(evs)
scree(evs, pc=FALSE)

evsfa <- fa(evs, nfactors=2, rotate="oblimin")
fa.diagram(evsfa)
fa.plot(evsfa)
```

Comment: Please, try this code: https://pastebin.com/NZJEz7J9  and see if you can draw point labels.

Comment: Yes, I get the points labeled as P and then 1 through 24. But is there a way to label them with the names of the corresponding items instead?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Please, edit your post adding the code and data that you are using. It will be easier to help you.

Comment: I edited the post. Is this enough? Or do you need specific info about the dataset I'm using? It's basically survey data.

Comment: OK. You should now add the code to extract point labels. They should be available in the `evs` data set. Maybe using `labs <- rownames(evs)` ?

Comment: Ah, I just realized I was a bit imprecise. When I said row names I meant the names of the rows as they show up in the `fa` output, like I'm now getting the row numbers from that output as labels. With respect to the original dataset those would of course be the column names. I did already try some stuff with the labels= argument, such as `labels=c("var1", "var2", "var3", etc.)` but that all didn't work. I also tried `labs <- colnames(evs)` just now and then `labels=labs`, but it didn't work either....

Comment: Yip indeed, I have 22 variables in the dataset and `fa.plot` produces a plot with 22 data points. Using the code with `fa(t(evs))` produces an error. But would using the transpose matrix not lead to a factor analysis where each observation row would be considered a variable?

Comment: Try using `labs <- rownames(evsfa$loadings)` and `fa.plot(evsfa), choose=1:2, labels=labs)`. If this not solve your problem, please add to your post the error message generated by `fa.plot`.

Comment: Yay, that did it! Thanks so much. It seems I can't add a photo here in the comments, but yes each data point now has the variable names next to it. If you happen to know whether there's a way to nudge the labels, that would be most awesome (I tried `nudge_x` without success, but I suppose it's an argument native to `ggplot2`). But this is already very helpful to make interpreting the graph easier!